# Fallback for typesafe-i18n by ivanhofer?

Tags: internationalization, sveltekit

I am working on i18n for an application in svelte and i am using typesafe-i18n by ivanhofer.
I do not have certain translated keywords and wish to have a fallback back to en for that particular string that is missing.

I read through the codebase but could not find anything

here is the link to their github repo: [link](https://github.com/ivanhofer/typesafe-i18n/tree/main)